# toggle elements jquery

Tags: javascript

I have a three `a` tags on a page. User can "select" only one.
Markup:

```
<div class="fl_near">
  <span class="title">title</span>
  <p>
    <a id="filter_today" class="first_tb" style="display: block">
      <span>text1</span>
    </a>
    <a id="filter_tomorrow">
      <span>text2</span>
    </a>
    <a id="filter_afterTomorrow" class="last_tb selected" style="display: block">
      <span>text3</span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$('.fl_near').find('a:not(.selected)').click(function () {
    alert('1');
        $('.fl_near').find('a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

This code not works properly. If I select first or second tag then all OK - style is switched, but alert shows anyway. If I select first then I can't select the last.
Where is a problem and why?
Thanks.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/28wzk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't bind click handler to the last element.

Try

```
$('.fl_near a').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});​
```

Comment: oh, It is my carelessness. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `find` filter runs only once - it is not listening for successive clicks. Use event delegation for this - that way the filter will be applied when the click occurs, not, as currently, when you bind the event.

```
$('.fl_near').on('click', 'a:not(.selected)', function (evt) {
    alert(1);
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('a').removeClass('selected');
});
```

Note also I've simplified your add/remove-class line.

Answer (score 1):

As it is now, you're not binding the click event to the link that is selected from start.

I would change:

```
$('.fl_near').find('a:not(.selected)').click(function () {
```

to

```
$('.fl_near a').click(function () {
```

Comment: You forget that the last element has the class `selected`, and you find the elements that hasn't got that class